# Use Google-Signin to log into App but stay signed out on Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, google-signin

I have integrated Google-Signin into an iOS Application and it works well as far as signing in or signing up is concerned.

The only problem is that, I dont want the user to be logged into Google on iOS Safari after I have used Google-Signin.

I have verified that, before I log into my app, I am signed out of google in iOS Safari. Then I go to my app and I use Google-Signin to log into my app, once that is done I then go back to iOS Safari and refresh the google page and all of a sudden it shows me signed in with the same account that I used to log in to the app.

How do i just use Google-Signin to simply log into the app and stay logged out of iOS safari?

Answer (score 1):

I've researched the topic and it seems the only way to perform logout is to use SFSafariViewController to open provider's logout page

For Google this is https://accounts.google.com/logout

This way requires some additional UX changes, because this action will open Safari window for a second and user should not be confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use GIDSignIn it will open safariviewcontroller inside the app.

Answer (score -1):

You can change which content from your Google Account syncs with the Apple apps on your device. You can also remove your Google Account from your Apple apps at any time, which stops syncing.

To change what syncs or remove your Google Account:

On your iPhone or iPad, open the Settings app.
Select `Mail, Contacts, Calendars or Safari`
Choose the account you'd like to edit or remove.
 Make the changes you want.
To change what content syncs: Next to the content you want to sync, turn on the switch. Turn it off for content you don't want to sync.
        To remove your account: Select Delete Account.